# Get the variable map from process instance

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

Is there a way to get the variable map from the process instance or i have to use the execution , using execution will not  help me always in getting the variable map of the process instance since one process instance might have more than one execution

Comment: Readers: note the bpmn tag. Here, *process* is likely referring to a business process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've faced with similar issues. You need an execution to get variable map. As you said there can be more than one execution for a given process instance. So you need to find the root execution where your variables reside. I've written some code to find root execution. I've tested it against a process that has more than one nested call activities. I haven't tried it against sub-processes but I think you can get it work:

```
ExecutionEntity executionEntity = (ExecutionEntity) runtimeService.createExecutionQuery().executionId(executionId).singleResult();
if (executionEntity == null) {
    return null;
}
String parentId = executionEntity.getParentId();
boolean parentNotEmpty = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(parentId);
String superExecutionId = executionEntity.getSuperExecutionId();
boolean superNotEmpty = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(superExecutionId);
if (parentNotEmpty) {
    return getRootExecution(parentId);
} else if (superNotEmpty) {
    return getRootExecution(superExecutionId);
} else {
    return executionEntity;
}
```

This snippet gets any execution id that belongs to your process instance, you can give any of them. It returns the root execution. Then using this code you can get your variable:

```
Object variable = getRuntimeService().getVariable(rootExecutionId, variableName);
```

Comment: @BOB glad to hear it, you can sign it as an answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: How? i am not that familiar with stack and have no time to read the guide. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService.getVariable*(*)`, it gives you access to all process instance variables. Of course you need an execution ID in order to identify the process instance. If this is not what you are looking for, please refine your question.

Comment: i need to get the variable using process instance id not execution id since using execution id is not efficient specially when the process instance has more than execution id